# Twitter API always return false

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I tried to post tweets using this [opensource API](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php). I have created Twitter App and received all needed keys (4 keys). So I don't understand why my script is wrong.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once("libs/twitter/TwitterAPIExchange.php");

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "...",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "...",
    'consumer_key' => "...",
    'consumer_secret' => "..."
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$requestMethod = 'POST';

/** POST fields required by the URL above. See relevant docs as above **/
$postfields = array(
    'status' => 'Hi, I am new status from Social Poster!'
);

/** Perform a POST request and echo the response **/
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$result = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->setPostfields($postfields)
             ->performRequest();
var_dump($result);
```

`var_dump` shows *false*.

Comment: simply don't work, no errors, no exceptions only false in response result.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but just for anyone who is having the same problem, here is the solution:

In your `TwitterAPIExchange.php` file, go to the `performRequest` method and change your `$options` variable from

```
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    );
```

to this:

```
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //this is what you need to add
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, it really help me :)